# Why View can't show the Group Radio Widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I add Group Radio widget in XML, but its not show in View when I call selectLevel().
My code:

```
public void selectLevel(){
     RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);  
     radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()  
        {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                //---displays the ID of the RadioButton that is checked---

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("Level %d", checkedId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();


            }
        });
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <com.v2nhat.myPikachu.View.QuickPlayView/>

   <RadioGroup >

        <RadioButton/>
        <RadioButton/>

   </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

I would put your code in onCreate, and store the RadioGroup as a field of your activity. I think that would make more sense than calling another function and not being able to refer to the RadioGroup outside of it.